# Finding element using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to gather an element with the class name `crash_crashGameCoefficient__M8rxs` using selenium. My current code is listed below and just returns and empty list when it should be returning the item with the class name `crash_crashGameCoefficient__M8rxs`. Please help!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, json, colorama
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

x = []
y = []

chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe'

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)

URL = 'https://bloxflip.com/crash'

driver.get(URL)

thing = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('crash_crashGameCoefficient__M8rxs')

print(thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could cause the issue is the page getting loaded too slowly before the `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` looks for the element. Test by adding an implicit wait `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`, this could be changed to a more suitable fluent wait if necessary.

Comment: I'm getting this weird error(s), any solutions? https://pastebin.com/NdC7x3bs

Comment: Have you tried using `find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=crash_crashGameCoefficient__M8rxs)` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('crash_crashGameCoefficient__M8rxs')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

URL = 'https://bloxflip.com/crash'

driver.get(URL)

thing = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@class,'crash_crashGameCoefficient__')]")))
print(thing)
```

Should be a simple wait for the element to be present.